# Firebase REST API GET request with params

Tags: rest, api, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've uploaded a geojson file to my firebase realtime database and setup an http get request in my angular app to retrieve the data.  Here's a small sample of my data.  All it is is an array of objects.  Each object is a zip code.  Below are two zip code objects.

```
[
   {
      "type":"Feature",
      "properties":{
         "STATEFP10":"44",
         "ZCTA5CE10":"02818",
         "GEOID10":"4402818",
         "CLASSFP10":"B5",
         "MTFCC10":"G6350",
         "FUNCSTAT10":"S",
         "ALAND10":56516634,
         "AWATER10":8882294,
         "INTPTLAT10":"+41.6429192",
         "INTPTLON10":"-071.4857186",
         "PARTFLG10":"N"
      },
      "geometry":{
         "type":"Polygon",
         "coordinates":[
            [
               [
                  -71.457848,
                  41.672076
               ],
               [
                  -71.457848,
                  41.672414
               ],
               [
                  -71.457848,
                  41.672932
               ],
               [
                  -71.457916,
                  41.67407
               ]
            ]
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "type":"Feature",
      "properties":{
         "STATEFP10":"44",
         "ZCTA5CE10":"02878",
         "GEOID10":"4402878",
         "CLASSFP10":"B5",
         "MTFCC10":"G6350",
         "FUNCSTAT10":"S",
         "ALAND10":75250623,
         "AWATER10":8363563,
         "INTPTLAT10":"+41.6101375",
         "INTPTLON10":"-071.1804709",
         "PARTFLG10":"N"
      },
      "geometry":{
         "type":"Polygon",
         "coordinates":[
            [
               [
                  -71.210351,
                  41.656166
               ],
               [
                  -71.209897,
                  41.657718
               ],
               [
                  -71.208399,
                  41.660013
               ],
               [
                  -71.20787,
                  41.661323
               ]
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

I can retrieve all of my data no problem but I can't seem to filter specific zip codes.  I have read over the guides on firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data) and can not get this to work with params.  What I'm trying to do is filter an object based on the "ZCTA5CE10" value in "properties".  I have tried many different combinations.  Below is one of them:

```
getZipData() {
  return this.http.get(this.url + '?orderBy="properties/ZCTA5CE10"&equalTo="02818"');
}
```

I get a 400 error when attempting to use params.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, Is it possible to filter multiple zip codes E.g. &equalTo="02818"&equalTo="02878"

Comment: What is the value of this.url? [And it is not possible to filter multiple zip codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26700924/4916627)

Comment: Also your data does not look like valid firebase data because firebase doesnt support arrays in that way.

Comment: My url is just the path to my Firebase database.   I know Firebase converts arrays into key value pairs which is why it makes this a little tricky.  I was able write a rule in Firebase that allowed me to orderBy the index of the index number assigned to each object in Firebase.  I think I can map it correctly from here but is there a way to have multiple equalTo’s ?  How can I retrieve 3 specific zip codes at once?

Comment: It looks like multiple equalTo's are not possible.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I imported your data and the query works for me: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/49809560.json?orderBy="properties/ZCTA5CE10"&equalTo="02818"&print=pretty

Comment: Yea I got it working.  Now I'm just trying to upload a very large json file to Firebase RTDB because firestore doesn't support an array of arrays which is needed for geojson.